# Pycharm, requirement already satisfied but is not added to packages

Tags: python, pycharm, package, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to run [this project](https://github.com/gkotsis/negation-detection) on this environment:

pycharm ver2018.2.4 + Windows 10 + python 2.7.

I could install its requirements but one of them (stanford_corenlp_pywrapper==0.1.0) cannot be installed. When I try to install it via windows command line, it was successful

[image: command line in win10]

but it wasn't added to pycharm env and still shows  "package requirement stanford_corenlp_pywrapper==0.1.0 is not satisfied". It is not exist even at the list of available packages and so couldn't add it.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Pycharm interpreter]

Comment: Have you tried installing it in the PyCharm's cmd? Is it installing succesfully there? If not tried, give it a try. It might work there.

Comment: have you tried creating conda environment and install the requirements ??

Answer (score 0):

You have created a virutal env when creating a project. So system level packages i.e via `pip install` in your cmd won't migrate here. You need to install packages again for your virtual environment by using the PyCharm command prompt.

Just run `pip install <package>` there again for all your packages and they should be present in your virtual env.

Or else while creating a new project you can also check the box that says `inherit global packages` to get all packages that were in your system.

Also, You can activate your virtual environment from your cmd(if you know how) then run pip install there, so packages will be installed in that environment again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. First I was using a virtual environment through Pycharm, and second when I tried to use Pycharm to find the package it could not (package doesn't exist using conda install package_name).

For example, I was missing the package gmplot. When I used the Pycharm terminal it would NOT install the package telling me the Requirement already satistified.

[image: Pycharm]

1. What did to fix was open up my Anaconda Powershell Prompt
2. Conda activate my environment (conda activate bmrl)
3. pip install gmplot

This time it worked. I did the install to the virtual environment using pip from the Anaconda prompt. Don't know why it failed in the Pycharm terminal (see below)?

[image: anaconda prompt and pip install]